# What's the purpose of declare var System: any?

Tags: typescript

In Angular material's source code (https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io), there is a typings.d.ts file. It includes a type definition:

declare var System: any;

Wondering what's purpose of this type?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick breakdown of the parts...

```
declare /* an ambient type, not implement here */
var /* a variable */
System /* named "System" */
: any; /* with no type information - assume it is compatible with any type */
```

As an example, if I had a script that TypeScript didn't know would be loaded at runtime, I would use this statement in order to suppress type errors. Without this ambient type, the compiler will complain about all references to `System` in your code because it can't see the type.